# vimeo video as .mp4 format in android

Tags: android, video, vimeo

i want to play vimeo video in my android application, to play i need video as .mp4 format.
i have user below link to get the video as .mp4 format, when i hit this url in browser it will ask me to save the file as an .mp4 format ,but when i try to get the same thing though coding it will gives an error.(file not found). can anybody help me to play vimeo video in my android application, or any other way to do this?
http://vimeo.com/moogaloop/play/clip:7926539/f44f7a1dc39fb9b6ebede558e459274e/1310792258

Thanks.

Comment: last two parameters are like tokens and changes after certain period so you need to get those parameters each time when request for the video. try to get the last two parameters (request_signature and request_signature_expired) each time from http://vimeo.com/moogaloop/load/clip:<videoID>