# Play Vimeo Videos in Windows 7 phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, video, vimeo

I am trying to get Vimeo videos to play in a windows 7 phone app. I used the answer here: [How can I find download links for vimeo videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460394/how-can-i-find-download-links-for-vimeo-videos) to get a Vimeo URL that looks like this:

http://vimeo.com/moogaloop/play/clip:29415171/f44f7a1dc39fb9b6ebede558e459274e/1310792258

The problem is when I use a non-mobile web browser the video will redirect you to the MP4 version of the file which plays correctly but if played on my Win7 phone (any browser) it doesn’t work. Instead I get a “We are having trouble displaying this page” and a “Error: HTTP 500 Server Internal error”.

Does anyone know how to work around this to get the video to play? Maybe another approach entirely?

I saw this similar question here [vimeo video as .mp4 format in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715474/vimeo-video-as-mp4-format-in-android) for the Android but its 2 months old and no one has even commented or answered. I know it’s possible to play Vimeo videos in W7 Phone because there are apps for it.

Any help would be appreciated. As always thanks in advance.

Comment: It must be possible because fo http://www.wpcentral.com/vimeo-player-review I'd guess they are either accessing a different format source or are converting the format themselves on the fly (using something like http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ManagedMediaHelpers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Vimeo has now added mobile support for Win 7 phones on its site. So if you go to a Vimeo video http://vimeo.com/m// a page will open that will allow you to play and successfully watch the video.

This is not the best solution, as I would rather have a direct link to the video, but for now it's a working solution. If in the future I figure out a way to directly link to the video files I will post it here (or if someone else has done this I would love to know how you did it)

Answer (score 0):

For starters, ensure the version of Windows Phone being tested in Windows Phone 7 Mango. As that version has IE 9 with HTML5 video support.

I then believe you need a [paid Vimeo account to create mobile videos](http://www.vimeo.com/pro).

Comment: I have the mango update. Windows Phone v7.5 and Windows Phone OS v7.1  I am not sure how to check the version of IE tho, didnt see that option. Either way it should be the newest version of IE and it doesnt work.

Comment: @crazymatt Windows Phone 7.5 includes IE 9. There isn't a notice in Mobile IE though. But mobile encoded Vimeo videos do work in IE 9 mobile. I have seen one or two of them on my developer Mango handset.