# play vimeo video using media launcher in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can i play vimeo video using media launcher ,my code:

```
MediaPlayerLauncher mediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher();
mediaPlayerLauncher.Media = new Uri("http://www.vimeo.com/39485693", UriKind.Absolute);
mediaPlayerLauncher.Location = MediaLocationType.Data;
mediaPlayerLauncher.Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.Pause | MediaPlaybackControls.Stop;
mediaPlayerLauncher.Orientation = MediaPlayerOrientation.Landscape;
mediaPlayerLauncher.Show();
```

but video is not playing , may be because of the video format . Any solution ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Did you try with other formats?

Comment: This is the link of an `HTML` page, not a video link. A video link ends with extensions like `mp4`, `avi` etc

Comment: I know shaharyar , but how to get this type of link of vimeo video ?

Comment: I saw this similar question here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715474/vimeo-video-as-mp4-format-in-android` for the Android but no one has answered. I know it’s possible to play Vimeo videos in W7 Phone because there are apps for it.